# paho-mqtt stops listening on configured topics

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt

I have a portion of python-code in some scripts which stops working irregularly.
I use the on_message callback to subscribe topics but after some hours (anywhere between 8 hours and two days) no mqtt messages are processed any more. I even cannot see a socket to mqtt broker any more, so I guess there is anywhere a retry or reconnect missing?

from the script below I still can see the "in try loop" messages occuring.

I have a try-except in the on message callback as I noticed that any exception there also lead to terminating the connection to the mqtt broker.

This code is in more than one script running, the issue occurs everywhere. It is not hardware or connection-dependent.

```py
def start_keyble(command):
    print("start_keyble with value " + command)
    cmd = '/usr/local/bin/keyble-sendcommand --address XXXXXXXXXXXX --user_id 1 --user_key YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY --command ' + str(command)
    output = os.popen(cmd).readlines()
    print("start_keyble will return ")
    print(output)
    return output

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    try:
        if (str(message.topic).endswith("/set") and str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")) != ''):
            param = str(message.topic)
            value = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
            print("set parameter " + param + " with value " + value + " requested")
            newstate = start_keyble(value)
            #mqttc.publish("Garagentuere/status", str(newstate), 0)
            for line in newstate:
                if (line != ""):
                    mqttc.publish("Garagentuere/status", str(line), 0)
                    time.sleep(1)
    except Exception:
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
...
    mqttw = paho.Client('equiva-watcher', clean_session=True)
    mqttw.on_message=on_message
    mqttw.connect(BROKER_HOST, BROKER_PORT, 60)
    mqttw.loop_start()
    mqttw.subscribe([("Garagentuere/status/set", 0)])

    while True:
        try:
            print("in try-loop")
            time.sleep(FREQUENCY)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        except Exception:
            raise
```

Comment: Does each instance of the script have a different client id (`equiva-watcher`)?

Comment: yes, it / they have.
each script has a publisher connector (in this case 'equiva-connector' as clientID) and a subscribe watcher (in this case 'equiva-watcher'), so they have different client-IDs. the different scripts itself have different names, so the "equiva" part is exchanged by the type of device I "attach" and the names are unique.